# Rails error on windows 10 (An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsinstaller

I have installed Rails version 5.1.3 on windows 10 via RailsInstaller and I tried to create a new application:

```sh
C:\RubyOnRails>rails new Hello
```

I'm getting an error installing sqlite3:

> sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.

Complete log:

```
    create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Amin/RubyOnRails/Hello/.git/
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/update
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  package.json
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb
         run  bundle install
The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.3.
To update, run `gem install bundler`
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.8.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using crass 1.0.4
Using rack 2.0.7
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using arel 8.0.0
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using bindex 0.7.0
Using bundler 1.15.3
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using thor 0.20.3
Using ffi 1.10.0 (x86-mingw32)
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using puma 3.12.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rubyzip 1.2.2
Using tilt 2.0.9
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.1
Installing sqlite3 1.4.1 with native extensions
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using childprocess 1.0.1
Using i18n 1.6.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using nokogiri 1.10.3 (x86-mingw32)
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using mail 2.7.1
Using addressable 2.6.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 4.1.20
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190501-25092-bytgcn.rb
extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

I remember a while ago, I managed to installed rails on windows 7 from scratch and I had not installed any depedencies. I am not sure if rails is conflicting with anything?

Thanks

Comment: On windows 10 using WSL is better to go with Rails development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try lowering version of sqlite in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~>1.3.13'
```

This version looks to be the last at the moment that has mingw32 variant published.

sqlite3 1.4.0 was published 4 Feb 2019, before that date above version was the latest and thus you were able to install without any modifications

Comment: this brings me to a new problem ``require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0):

This requires native extension. So you need to install SQLite separately on your Windows machine. Download and install SQLite from https://sqlite.org/download.html. And then run

`bundle install`

Comment: didnt work either. i already have sqlite long time before rails. i believe your method is the one who cause my current error